# Resize main partition with gparted

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, linux-mint, gparted

I'm trying to create a dual-boot machine, having Linux Mint 12 installed already. I have only one partition that occupies the whole hdd space. I want to cut some space from it and create a new partition for windows, but in gparted all options for this partition (delete, resize/move) are disabled. What should I do to create the new partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you are trying to accomplish this task? on booted up host system? If yes, You should start system from CD (ubuntu or similar) and then resize partition